# AutoSync Time periodically

Tags: cron, time, daemons, ntp

My Catalina weirdly have drifting time, sometimes 5 minutes, 10 minutes, 19 minutes (in 1-2 hours), today it's drifting 40 minutes (in 4 hours). Is there any brew package/daemon that automatically sync the time every for example 5 minutes?

already using this, but it's still drifting few minutes
[image]

I've tried:

```
crontab -e 
* * * * * sntp -sS sg.pool.ntp.org 
* * * * * sudo sntp -sS sg.pool.ntp.org
```

but both resulting an error:

```
sntp 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Tue Mar 21 14:36:42 UTC 2017 (139~6597)
Can't open KOD db file /var/db/ntp-kod for writing: Permission denied
2021-10-14 09:59:00.339248 (-0700) +9.756839 +/- 6.545621 sg.pool.ntp.org 194.0.5.123 s2 no-leap
step-systime: Operation not permitted
```

or

```
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, `sudo crontab -e` solved the issue

but the bad part, the result log can't be seen on `/var/mail/[username]`